# If $u_n$ converges weakly to $u$. Does $|u_n|$ converges weakly to $|u|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

This question comes from the proof of Theorem 1 in [E.N.Dancer's paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700012089). (page 427 line 13-14)

**Question:**

Suppose $u_n$ converges weakly to $u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Does $|u_n|$ converges weakly to $|u|$ in $L^2(\Omega)$?

**My Attempt**

From the facts that

1.) weak convergence $\Rightarrow$ norm-boundedness $\Rightarrow$ subsequence weak convergence.

2.) If every subsequence contains a weakly convergent subsubsequence, then the whole sequence converges weakly.

We know that $|u_n|$ converges weakly to some $v \in L^2(\Omega)$. But I don't know how to show $v = |u|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. In $\Omega = (0,1)$, consider the sequence $\{u_n\}$ given by
$$u_n(t) = \operatorname{sign}(\sin(\pi \, n \, t)).$$
Then, it is easy to check that $u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ but $|u_n| \equiv 1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Let $e_k:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb C, t\mapsto e^{ikt}$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$. Then $(\frac{1}{2\pi}e_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,2\pi]$ and thus converges weakly to $0$ for $k\to\infty$, but $|e_k|\equiv \frac{1}{2\pi}$ converges in norm to $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.